# How to group application in aosp launcher

Tags: android-source

[sample code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVrbk.jpg)

I have added similar kind of folder name & apps under favourite same as google group folder, but in my case the group folder is not getting created in desktop of the launcher.

Do I need to make changes in any other location or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you don't need to make any other changes, Make sure whatever app you are adding as favorite app, under the folder tag, those apps should be installed in the device.

For the app folder, at least the device should have installed more than one favorite app then only it will appear in the folder.